# Unable to understand how pyspark statements work without importing on my cluster

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I am using Azure Databricks connected to a Databricks runtime 13.0. Then, I could run this command without importing pyspark:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

How is this possible?

I was expecting to write like i typically do:
Import the library and then use it.

For example:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
```

Answer (score 1):

It's just a standard behavior of Python packages, well described in the Python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) - you can import individual modules if you have correct directory layout without needing to import top-level package.